Embedding a LPN based encryption ciphertext into a Finite Field
If you are using LPN encryption scheme in practical scenario how big are the ciphertexts if your security parameter is 40, 128 or 256 bits?
The reason I ask is because I would like to take a ciphertext from LPN and 'embed' it into a Finite Field say for example F = GF(2^(128)). Would this be possible or are the ciphertexts from LPN too big to be practically 'embedded' into a Finite Field?
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8365093
https://wiki.epfl.ch/edicpublic/documents/Candidacy%20exam/Cryptography_from_learning_parity_with_noise.pdf

please provide context, define the LPN scheme you are talking about with parameters

I am looking at some papers for example:
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8365093
and
https://wiki.epfl.ch/edicpublic/documents/Candidacy%20exam/Cryptography_from_learning_parity_with_noise.pdf

please put the links in the body of the question, comments can disappear sometimes.

Absent any further information about the scheme, there are some essential limitation on how hard a well-posed LPN problem can be.
We write $n$ for the number of unknown bits in a secret $\mathbf s$ and $m$ for the number of samples $(a_i,b_i)$ with $\mathbf a_i\cdot\mathbf s+\mathbf e_i=\mathbf b_i$ provided to the attacker where $\mathbf e_i$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli variables with parameter $\tau$. We write $\lambda$ for the security bound (measured in bits).
Firstly, you would want the values $\mathbf e_i$ to be unguessable. In a strict cryptographic sense, you should aim that the collection of $\mathbf e_i$ have min-entropy at least $\lambda$. Thus, for $\tau<1/2$, we require $-m\mathrm {lg}\tau>\lambda$. (You would also want $\mathbf s$ to be unguessible, this will be automatic if the components of $\mathbf s$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli variables with parameter 0.5 and $m>n$, which is the most common case).
You would also want the causal solution to be unique. We can model the number of satisfied equations for  non-causal candidates as $2^n-1$ i.i.d. samples from a $\mathrm{Bin}(m,0.5)$ distribution, and the number of satisfied equation for our causal candidate as a sample from $\mathrm{Bin}(m,1-\tau)$. We wish the latter sample to be greater than all of the previous samples with very high probability (the tolerance for decryption failure may or may not be the same as the security parameter). Absolute concentration inequalities such as Chernoff bounds will help provide parameter sets where this requirement is met.
Looking at the first requirement, for 128-bits of security you would have to take $m>128$ and assuming that the samples correspond to a ciphertext in your scheme, this could not be embedded into $GF(2^{128})$ without information loss.
For any givens scheme there could be additional constraints depending on the effectiveness of different attacks (e..g information set decoding) against the parameter sets in question. A good example might be the Classic McEliece where the best known attack is roughly(*) the same as attacking an LPN system and ciphertexts are a few thousand bits in size for 128 or 256-bits of security.

(*) I do not endorse basing rigorous security estimates on this statement.
